# Prononciation du mot "haricot"

Tags: prononciation, étymologie, h-aspiré

Je sais que l'h du mot "haricot" est aspiré. Le haricot ; les haricot (pas d'élision ; pas de liaison).

1. J'ai entendu plusieurs fois des natifs dire "les haricots verts" en faisant la liaison entre les et haricots. Plusieurs fois j'ai dû consulter le lemme haricot dans un dictionnaire pour montrer que l'h est aspiré. Est-ce une nouvelle tendance de prononciation qui s'impose ou seulement de l'ignorance ?
2. Question connexe : je me demande pourquoi l'h de haricot est aspiré.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Tous les dictionnaires disent en effet que le *H* du mot "haricot" est aspiré.
2. La théorie indique qu'un *H* hérité du latin n'est pas aspiré et qu'un *H* provenant d'une autre langue l'est, avec quelques exceptions de part et d'autre. Comme plus grand monde ne connaît le latin ou l'étymologie de chaque mot en *H*, l'usage, comme pour toutes les prononciations, consiste à prononcer comme on entend les autres le faire, ou alors comme on nous a dit de le faire quand on s'est fait corriger par ses professeurs ou ses parents.

   **Tous** les enfants commencent par prononcer ***les z'haricots*** puis la plupart modifient cette prononciation sous la pression de leur entourage car cette liaison est particulièrement stigmatisée.

   De nos jours, il me semble que de plus en plus de gens considèrent qu'il y a plus important que cette liaison dans la vie, et se fichent donc de la manière dont *les haricots* est prononcé, vu qu'il n'y a pas de risque d'incompréhension. Il y a donc bien une probable évolution vers la liaison.

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse ! "...sous la pression de leur entourage car cette liaison est particulièrement stigmatisée." Stigmatisée ? Pourquoi ?

Comment: Stigmatisée car c'est précisément cet exemple que l'on apprend tous à l'école, *haricot* est largement le plus connu des mots n'entraînant pas de liaison et pour lesquels pourtant on l'observe souvent.

Comment: "Handicapés" était un bon candidat aussi avant de devenir politiquement incorrect...

Answer (score 6):

Haricot est réputé être un de ces mots dont le h aspiré est instable. C'est loin d'être le seul, voir aussi l'handicapé/le handicapé ; l'hamburger/le hamburger ; l'harassement/le harassement ; l'anse/la anse ; l'auvent/le auvent, toutes des paires qui présentent beaucoup de variation parmi la population (parfois dans une zone géographique précise, parfois non).

Quant à la raison pour le h aspiré, il s'explique facilement pour le haricot au sens de ragout (il descend d'un /h/ germanique), mais beaucoup moins pour le légume. Je reproduis en l'adaptant un peu la section étymologie de l'entrée "haricot" du TLFi][1](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/haricot):

Sens 1 (ragout): déverbal de l'anc. verbe harigoter "déchiqueter, mettre en lambeaux" (1176-81, Chrétien de Troyes, Chevalier Lion, éd. M. Roques, 831), lequel est probablement un dérivé en -oter (cf. tapoter) de l'ancien bas francique. *hariôn "gâcher", prononcé *harijôn (d'où l'allemand verheeren "dévaster, détruire", ou l'anglais harry "harrasser, piller") et entré en Gallo-Romania sous la forme *harigôn. Hericot est peut-être dû à l'infl. d'écot "rameau élagué imparfaitement, chicot d'arbuste", le rapprochement de ces deux mots s'expliquant sans doute par le fait que la viande du haricot de mouton est découpée en morceaux irréguliers.

Sens 2 (légume): origine très discutée (v. FEW t. 16, p. 167b). Probablement issu de 1, ce légume entrant très souvent dans la composition du haricot de mouton. Un emprunt au mexica ayacotli (FEW t. 1, p. 190b) semble moins vraisemblable. Quant à l'hypothèse selon laquelle haricot serait issu de Calicut "Calcutta", lieu d'origine présumé de ce légume, elle doit être rejetée étant donné que l'expression *fève de callicot* (1651, Bonnefons, Le Jardinier françois, p. 207) est postérieure à *feve d'aricot* (1628).

La deuxième partie de cette notice est largement empruntée [au FEW](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/136156), qui rentre plus dans les détails mais arrive à la même conclusion.

Il semble probable que, même si le haricot légume (j'avais initialement écrit l'haricot) ne descend pas directement du haricot ragout, il a subi son influence (la derivation de /arikɔ/ à partir de /kalikɔ(t)/ ou de /ayakɔt/ est loin d'être évidente...), notamment par l'adjonction d'un h aspiré.