# Pronunciation websites and pronunciation of haricot

Tags: prononciation, h-aspiré

to which source/website do you go to if you want to know how a specific word is pronounced?

So far I only know of Forvo. Unfortunately, I do not see that the académie française provides any help on that (not even given a representation in the IPA).

I come up with this question because I am uncertain of how the word "haricot" (bean) is pronounced. The académie française says that the h is aspirated but I have never heard a french speaker do so (and yes, I have read [Prononciation du mot "haricot"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44766/prononciation-du-mot-haricot))

Comment: An excellent site for listening to pronunciation is [Projet shtooka](https://shtooka.net/index.php), ([their wikipedia page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shtooka)). Wiktionnaire usually gives IPA and very often have one or several audio samples of the words (9 for [*haricot*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/haricot)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prononciation du mot "haricot"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44766/prononciation-du-mot-haricot)

Comment: Partial duplicate: [Lack of phonetic transcriptions in French & Audio Dictionaries with Pronunciations](/q/1191/11413) (title could be better; answers give a bunch of dictionaries with pronunciations.)

Answer (score 7):

"Aspirated" doesn't mean "pronounced" when talking about the French h, which is always silent. *[H aspiré](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/pronunciation/h-aspire/)* means that there cannot be any contractions or liaisons in front of the h, in comparison to *[h muet](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/pronunciation/h-muet/)*, which allows both.

For example:

*les haricots* is pronounced [le a ʁi ko]

*les habitudes* is pronounced [le za bi tyd]

*Habitudes* begins with *h muet* and therefore allows the liaison with preceding *les*.

Likewise, *le haricot* vs *l'habitude* - only the latter contracts with the preceding article.

Comment: Thanks! Do you also have a website where you go to to find pronounciation advice?

Comment: @sorry: If you haven't figured out how to read IPA pronunciations, none of the dictionaries are going to help you. But IPA isn't that hard; figure it out.

Comment: Lots of French natives pronounce [lezaʁiko], and not only children!

Comment: @None Oui mais c'est pas beau!

Comment: @PeterShor I do know how to read IPA but I don't know any website that provides it. Do you know any?